# Как преобразовать '2022-11-02 16:57' в "02.11.22"

Tags: python, xlrd

Необходимо даты из столбцов Excel перенести в отчет формата .pdf.

Используя модуль xlrd, даты отображаются '2022-11-02 16:57'

Вопрос: Как из '2022-11-02 16:57' сделать удобный и читаемый вид "02.11.22"

Мой код:

```
import xlrd
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

x = 63
y = 475

# Сбор данных с определенного столбца в Excel.
cells_date = tabl_list.col_slice(0, 1, 30)

# Отображение полученных данных из Excel в отчете .pdf
for cell_date in cells_date:
    canvas.drawString(x, y, cell_date.value)
    y -= 15
```

В итоге у меня получается столбец с датами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Преобразуйте строку в дату, а затем выводите дату в нужном формате.

Comment: Выдает ошибку трассировки:
ValueError: time data "text:'2022-11-02 16:57'" does not match format '%d.%m.%y'